# Resume Angular Timer by ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer

I am building a test prep app and wanted to associate a timer with each question.

I am using [Angular Timer](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/#/#bower).

A user can move forward and backward during the test. If a question has not yet been viewed, a new timer will start from 0. Otherwise, if the question has been viewed, the timer will pick up where it left off for that specific question ID.

I have been using `start` and `stop` timer each time the user changes question, but of course the timer has no idea which question it is associated with. I was thinking of using

```
$scope.$broadcast('timer-resume');
```

To resume where it left off, but again... this means the time will resume from whatever question it was on, not necessarily the associated question.

I am thinking I somehow need to associate unique IDs to each `timer`, but this means I would need to generate a new `timer` object each time?

```
<timer ng-hide="question_checked" id="{{question.id}}" autostart="false" interval="1000" >{{ minutes }}m {{ seconds }}s </timer>
<span ng-hide="!question_checked">{{ timer.minutes }}m {{ timer.seconds }}s</span>
```

How can I accomplish this? Basically, I need to tell a specific timer by ID to start/stop and send it the last saved time.

Comment: Would something like this work for you? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval 

Creating a unique interval for each specific question with a count of 1.

Comment: can you show us the page where your app is runing currently so we may help

Comment: @TheyCallMeSam Are you suggesting not using `Angular Timer`?

Comment: you may want to use sessionStorage or  localStorage to hold data and pick it whenever you need it

Comment: Take the source code https://github.com/siddii/angular-timer/blob/master/app/js/_timer.js and modify it to your needs. Or wrap it in your own custom directive.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?